# How to test useParam() function with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

Getting this error while testing a component having a hook useParam()
[image]

Comment: could you share the test code ?

Comment: @Megha Rawat I have same error also. How did you fix it?

Comment: Hope the answer I just posted, help you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
I fixed it using below code.
  jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useParams: () => ({
      connectionId: '12',
    }),
  }));
```